# Use user control in the same folder as the page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I get this message at runtime  of ASP.NET 2 page :

The page 'MyFolder/blabla.aspx' cannot use the user control 'MyFolder/MyControl.ascx', because it is registered in web.config and lives in the same directory as the page.

Of course I can separate them to 2 different folders and thus solve the problem, but the question is :

WTF !?!?! Why I can't put them in the same folder ?!
Why can't they all .. get along !?! :)

Thanks

Comment: Funny that I get this same exact error for a control I have which includes another control. It even says "The page 'MyCONTROL.aspc'...". Page != Control. So I guess having more than one Control in a single directory is a problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This limitation is by design due to an internal design consideration re: performance.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.aspx) for further info.

> **Remarks**
>
> The TagPrefixInfo class allows you to programmatically access and
>   modify tag-prefix information stored in a configuration file. It
>   provides the same functionality as the ASP.NET @**Register**
>   directive. Tag prefixes associate a "namespace" in ASP.NET to the
>   assemblies and namespaces that must be included for custom controls
>   and user controls to work properly. TagPrefixInfo objects are stored
>   as members of a [TagPrefixCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixcollection.aspx) object. The
>   [TagPrefixCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixcollection.aspx) class allows you to programmatically access
>   and modify the **controls** subsection of the **pages** section of a
>   configuration file.
>
> TagPrefixInfo objects are added to the collection using the **add**
>   element and specifying a value for the **tagPrefix** attribute along
>   with values for other relevant attributes. The other required
>   information varies based on the kind of control you will use with the
>   specified tag prefix:
>
> - If it is a user control, you must define the [TagPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.tagprefix.aspx), [TagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.tagname.aspx), and [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.source.aspx) properties.
> - If it is a custom control, you must define the [TagPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.tagprefix.aspx), [Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.namespace.aspx), and [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.assembly.aspx) properties. The [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.tagprefixinfo.assembly.aspx)
>     property is not required if the control is in the application code
>     directory. The same **tagPrefix** value can be used to map to multiple
>     assemblies or namespaces.
>
> **Note** When a source is specified, the user control itself must not be in the same directory as the page. If it is, you get a run-time
>   error when you attempt to load the page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the performance point? I'm just curious.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw I suspect it's something to do with how ASP.NET WebForms compiles entire directories at once (so each directory of .aspx/ascx/master files gets its own output assembly in the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` directory.

Answer (score 8):

If you register it in the page or user control instead of the web.config it will load properly.
Add the following to the top of the page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MyControlTagPrefix" TagName="MyControlTagName" Src="~/MyFolder/MyControl.ascx" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you could do it without registering it, if it was essential.
You could probably have a PlaceHolder and then use .Controls.Add(LoadControl("path.ascx"))

But if it's not essential then put it in a different directory due to the reasons @Barry says.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found inside the .NET Framework Reference Source code for `System.Web.dll`:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/TagNameToTypeMapper.cs,ced01a48dbbb9f9c

`TryUserControlRegisterDirectives`

> Don't allow a config registered user control to be used by a page that lives in the same directory, to avoid circular references. More specifically, this would break batching because our simple dependency parser would not be able to detect the *implicit* dependency triggered by the presence of a tag (VSWhidbey 165042).