# Usercontrol launching an other usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have to do something special for a client :

I have a aspx page who call a usercontrol (a popup). On this usercontrol, I have a button who must call an other usercontrol (a second popup).

There is no trouble calling a usercontrol in the aspx page. 
But when I do the same operation in the usercontrol himself I throw this exception :

> Page '/WebUserControls/Popup/PopupPDF.ascx' can't use usercontrol
>   '/WebUserControls/Popup/PopupMail.ascx because it is registered in
>   web.config and resides in the same directory as the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964337/use-user-control-in-the-same-folder-as-the-page

Comment: If you provider a more complete example of your code we can shed more light on this and possibly offer a solution.

Just knowing that error to many assumptions are being made.

Answer (score 0):

Going on a whim here as an alternative solution.  You can manually load UserControls attached to an ASCX file with Code and you can load them from just about any directory on the site you want that way.

```
override CreateChildControls....
{
    var secondPopupControl = (MyControlsTypeThatInheritsFromUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/somepath/somecontrol.ascx");
    parentControlPopup.Controls.Add(secondPopupControl);
}
```